# Change the dropdown value based on the selected date in jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to change the dropdown value based on the date From 29-08-2020 to 08-09-2020 the dropdown values will be changed.. When user clicks on 29-08-2020 to 08-09-2020 from the datepicker the value of the dropdown has to to be changed..  Rest remaining dates when the user clicks the dropdown value will be different..How can I do it? Here is the code.In the below code the dropdown changes based on the day.. How I can change the dropdown based on the date.. Only from 29-08-2020 to 08-09-2020

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var date = new Date();
        var dayNo = date.getDay();
        var mindate = (5 - dayNo);
        var d = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'];
        var event = ['6.00 am : English', '7.00 am : Kannada', '8.00 am: Tamil'];
        var event1 = [' 7.00 am : Kannada', '9.00 am: English', '11.00 am: Tamil'];

        //Lest assume this is  event from database
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',

            minDate: mindate,
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                var today = new Date(dateText);
                var a = (d[today.getDay()]);
                $('#slDay').val(d[today.getDay()]);
                var html = '';
                $('#slDay').html('');
                if (d[today.getDay()] == 'sun')
                    $.each(event1, function (index, value) {
                        html += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'

                    });

                if (d[today.getDay()] == 'mon')
                    $.each(event, function (index, value) {
                        html += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'
                    });

                if (d[today.getDay()] == 'tue')
                    $.each(event, function (index, value) {
                        html += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'
                    });

                if (d[today.getDay()] == 'wed')
                    $.each(event, function (index, value) {
                        html += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'
                    });

                if (d[today.getDay()] == 'thu')
                    $.each(event, function (index, value) {
                        html += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'
                    });

                if (d[today.getDay()] == 'sat')
                    $.each(event, function (index, value) {
                        html += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'
                    });

                if (d[today.getDay()] == 'fri')
                    $.each(event, function (index, value) {
                        html += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'
                    });
                $('#slDay').append(html);
            }

        });
    });
</script>

<div class="form-group col-md-12 text">
    <label >Select Date<span style="color:red";> * </span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" name="date" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+2 days")); ?>" />
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-12 text">
    <label>Select Mass<span style="color:red";> * </span></label>
    <select class="form-control" required="" id='slDay' name="day">
        <option value="">---SELECT---</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the issue are you facing by using this code?
I think you just need to set "selected" property to make the option selected of the dropdown

Comment: I just want to change the dropdown value when the date between 29-08-2020 to 08-09-2020 is selected from the datepicker

Comment: I particular code is based on the day selected from the datepicker..

Comment: Which event you want show if dates are between `29-08-2020 to 08-09-2020` event1 or event ?

Comment: $.each(event, function (index, value) {
                        html += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'
                    });

Comment: Now the option value is changing  based on the day..

Comment: what about the dates other then `29-08-2020 to 08-09-2020` - what happens with those ?

Comment: Those dropdown will have different  values which is same based on day on the above code

Comment: From 29-08-2020 to 08-09-2020 the drop down value should change..Other than those days the dropdown value will remain same has that of above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply `store` all your dates between `29-08-2020 to 08-09-2020` in an array and check that using [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method to see if the the selected date is between `those` date.

On that basis you will `append` new option to your drop-down. If your `dates` are other then those `dates` then you can append `other value` in the drop-down.

**Live Demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var dayNo = date.getDay();
  var mindate = (5 - dayNo);
  var d = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'];
  var event = ['6.00 am : English', '7.00 am : Kannada', '8.00 am: Tamil'];
  var event1 = [' 7.00 am : Kannada', '9.00 am: English', '11.00 am: Tamil'];
  var event3 = [' 11.00 am : Kannada', '12.00 am: English', '13.00 am: Tamil'];
  var custDate = ['2020-08-29', '2020-08-30', '2020-08-31', '2020-09-01', '2020-09-02', '2020-09-03', '2020-09-04', '2020-09-05', '2020-09-06', '2020-09-07', '2020-09-08'];

  //Lest assume this is  event from database
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate: mindate,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var today = new Date(dateText);
      var a = (d[today.getDay()]);
      $('#slDay').val(d[today.getDay()]);
      var html = '';
      $('#slDay').html('');
      if (custDate.includes(dateText)) {
        $.each(event3, function(index, value) {
          html += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'
        });
      } else if (d[today.getDay()] == 'sun') {
        $.each(event1, function(index, value) {
          html += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'
        });
      } else {
        $.each(event, function(index, value) {
          html += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'
        });
      }
      $('#slDay').append(html);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-cViKBZswH231Ui53apFnPzem4pvG8mlCDrSyZskDE9OK2gyUd/L08e1AC0wjJodXYZ1wmXEuNimN1d3MWG7jaQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-YqF4f2cbm2jH7sEEu/iDJFjSQ/qUSzoiQIK2OQ3OFTsQQE5dxoCTYz1wZrTMv8ES8NYqOB5ChZU8jQdMaEv/yg==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="form-group col-md-12 text">
  <label>Select Date<span style="color:red" ;> * </span></label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" name="date" min="" />
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-12 text">
  <label>Select Mass<span style="color:red" ;> * </span></label>
  <select class="form-control" required="" id='slDay' name="day">
    <option value="">---SELECT---</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: When the date 29-08-2020 I have to change the event  var event3 = [' 11.00 am : Kannada', '12.00 am: English', '13.00 am: Tamil'];

Comment: saturday,sunday dates it is event1 else it is event2

Comment: just example.. Event is for days Monday to Saturday and Event1 is for Sunday and Event 3 is for The days betwen 29-08-2020 to 08-09-2020..

Comment: Even those dates between 29th to 8th sept will have the different events on weekdays as well as weekends

Comment: @user5742277 You said `saturday,sunday dates it is event1`  AND now you are saying Event1 is for Sunday

Comment: Event1 is for sunday. Monday to saturday Event

Comment: Its..Working fine..I have 1 doubt if I need to add different event for dates 29th to 8th. If those days has sunday the event has to be changed. How can I add that one?

Comment: @user5742277 Yes thats easy. You can excludes those date from the `custDate  array` and then you can do custom event between those dates as well on sat sun.

Comment: In elseif I need to add The excluded date or what?

Comment: @user5742277 yes that's correct. You can have another `else if` with for sat and sun falling between `29th to 8th` .